# Leaflet marker showing in wrong place (geojson)

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to insert crimes onto a map from an API and plot them onto the map using lat/lng. When clicking a poly it gives you the postcode name ie (LS19) it is pulling the coordinates from the geojson file however it is pulling the incorrect postcode (poly) area's coordinates so the markers aren't being plotted within the selected area. Is it possible to add some kind of detection and pull the coordinates dependent on postcode (poly) as each one has their own properties.name in the geojson file.

.features[0] should be [x] when any postcode area is clicked an integer updates.
the error lies somewhere around here (i presume)

```
        function zoomFeature(e) {
    mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    var colonString = statesdata
.features[0]
.geometry
.coordinates[0]
.map(pair => pair.reverse().join())
.join(':');
```

I have attached a working jsfiddle which shows the problem. if anybody could support me on this would be much appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/co486g93/2/

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question body. The live example is a nice to have. Furthermore, the provided JSFiddle live example does not work (`statesdata` undefined).